# Conditionally replace rows in lists

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have a sequence of matrices/lists

```
testlist = {{85, 75, 1}, {84, 74, 2}, {83, 73, 3}, {82, 72, 4}, 
            {81, 71, 5}, {80, 70, 6}, {79, 69, 7}, {78, 68, 8}, 
            {77, 67, 9}, {76, 66, 10}, {75, 65, 11}};
Table[list[H1R] = DeleteCases[testlist, a_ /; a[[1]] <= H1R || a[[2]] >= H1R],
      {H1R, 80, 78, -1}
]
```

namely

```
list[80] = {{85, 75, 1}, {84, 74, 2}, {83, 73, 3}, {82, 72, 4}, {81, 71, 5}}
list[79] = {{85, 75, 1}, {84, 74, 2}, {83, 73, 3}, {82, 72, 4}, {81, 71, 5}, 
            {80, 70, 6}}
list[78] = {{85, 75, 1}, {84, 74, 2}, {83, 73, 3}, {82, 72, 4}, {81, 71, 5},   
            {80, 70, 6}, {79, 69, 7}}
```

Now I'd like to be able to, in one shot, using `Table` or something, in all lists replace all records/rows where say the second element is between  `74.5` and `72.3` with a replacement row say `{-10,5,0.3}`

So at the end of my one shot operation or `Table`, I'll have:

```
list[80] = {{85, 75, 1}, {-10,5,0.3}, {-10,5,0.3}, {82, 72, 4}, 
             {81, 71, 5}}
list[79] = {{85, 75, 1}, {-10,5,0.3}, {-10,5,0.3}, {82, 72, 4}, 
            {81, 71, 5}, {80, 70, 6}}
list[78] = {{85, 75, 1}, {-10,5,0.3}, {-10,5,0.3}, {82, 72, 4}, 
            {81, 71, 5}, {80, 70, 6},  {79, 69, 7}}
```

These lists that I have generated for my example are very similar to each other but my actual lists are quite different and are non-integer and basically I would like to be able to scan all of the lists in one shot and replace certain rows by other rows provided the elements of the rows or functions of elements of the said row fall in some interval.

**Second Update:**

Mimicking what you guys have done, I did this because I didn't want to write {*,*.._} because I have 15 columns now and I might have more later:

```
Table[list[i]=list[i] /. a_ :> {-10, 5, 0.3} /;Dimensions[a] == {3} && 72.3 < a[[2]] < 74.5, {i, 78, 80}]
```

This code works. woohoo!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Replace[#, {_, _?(72.3 <= # <= 74.5 &), _} :> {-10, 5, 0.3}, Infinity] & /@ 
   {list[80], list[79], list[78]}

(*{{{85, 75, 1}, {-10, 5, 0.3}, {-10, 5, 0.3}, {82, 72, 4}, {81, 71,  5}},
  {{85, 75, 1}, {-10, 5, 0.3}, {-10, 5, 0.3}, {82, 72, 4}, {81,71, 5}, {80, 70, 6}}, 
  {{85, 75, 1}, {-10, 5, 0.3}, {-10, 5, 0.3}, {82, 72, 4}, {81, 71, 5}, {80, 70, 6}, {79, 69, 7}}}  *)
```

or `ReplaceAll`

```
  {list[80], list[79], list[78]} /. {_, _?(72.3 <= # <= 74.5 &), _} :> {-10, 5, 0.3}
```

**Update:** More generally,

```
rplc[k_, from_, to_, rplcmnt_] := 
   Replace[#, {Repeated[_, {k - 1}], _?(from <= # <= to &), ___} :> 
         rplcmnt, Infinity] & /@ {##} &
(* replace an element with `x` if its 3rd element is between 3 and 5 :*)
rplc[3, 3, 5, x][list[80], list[79], list[78]]
(* {{{85, 75, 1}, {84, 74, 2}, x, x, x}, 
    {{85, 75, 1}, {84, 74, 2}, x, x,  x, {80, 70, 6}},
    {{85, 75, 1}, {84, 74, 2}, x, x,  x, {80, 70, 6}, {79, 69, 7}}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks Kguler and R.M.! You guys rock! I can't wait to get competent at this stuff so I can help others like everyone here has helped me.

Comment: @Amatya That's the best way to give back to the community :) Good luck!

Comment: Hey guys, quick question.. what if the number of columns in my matrix is very large so that it's not feasible to write {_,_.._}. Is there some way to write check the kth coordinate where k is also a variable that I can alter depending on the situation?

Comment: @Amatya, thanks for the accept. You can use `{Repeated[_,k-1],_?(cond),___}` instead of `{_,_?(cond),_}` to cover the more general case where the `cond` is tested on the kth entry of each sublist. Similarly, `{Repeated[_,k-1],x_,___}` should work in R.M's method.

Comment: @Kguler thanks! I will do that. I had temporarily unaccepted the answer because I thought I needed to do that for anyone to notice the edit.

Comment: `Repeated[_,k-1]` should be `Repeated[_,{k-1}]` in the comment above.

Comment: @Kguler thanks! Your generalized solution is great. If you can also tell me what is wrong with my updated mimicry then that would be an awesome bonus. in any event.. thanks a million!

Comment: @Amatya, perhaps trying the example `list[80] /. a_ :> foo[a] /; a != 100` gives hints on how `ReplaceAll` processes the rules. If you change part of your code to `list[i] /. 
 a_ :> {-10, 5, 0.3} /; And[Length[a] >= 2, 72.3 < a[[2]] < 74.5]` it should work.

Comment: Hey Kgluer.. I did something exactly like that. I added an additional condition on Dimension (please see my updated question) and it totally worked. woohoo.. thanks for all your help.

Comment: @kguler, I was tormented by a simple replacement problem until I found your answer. The _? was the key. `b /. _?(1 < # &) :> 0` Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9):

Here's another solution using [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) and [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html):

```
Table[list[i] /. {_, x_, _} :> {-10, 5, 0.3} /; 72.3 < x < 74.5, {i, 78, 80}]

(* {{{85, 75, 1}, {-10, 5, 0.3}, {-10, 5, 0.3}, {82, 72, 4}, {81, 71, 5}, {80, 70, 6}, {79, 69, 7}}, 
    {{85, 75, 1}, {-10, 5, 0.3}, {-10, 5, 0.3}, {82, 72, 4}, {81, 71, 5}, {80, 70, 6}}, 
    {{85, 75, 1}, {-10, 5, 0.3}, {-10, 5, 0.3}, {82, 72, 4}, {81, 71, 5}}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list[80] = {{85, 75, 1}, {84, 74, 2}, {83, 73, 3}, {82, 72, 4}, {81, 71, 5}};

list[79] = {{85, 75, 1}, {84, 74, 2}, {83, 73, 3}, {82, 72, 4}, {81, 71, 5}, 
            {80, 70, 6}};

list[78] = {{85, 75, 1}, {84, 74, 2}, {83, 73, 3}, {82, 72, 4}, {81, 71, 5}, 
            {80, 70, 6}, {79, 69, 7}};
```

Using `ReplacePart`:

```
rules = Position[#, x_List /; Between[x[[2]], {72.3, 74.5}]] -> {-10, 5, 0.3} &;

ReplacePart[#, rules@#] & /@ {list[80], list[79], list[78]} // Column[#, Spacings -> 1] &
```

[image]

Comment: +1, nice employment of `ReplacePart`

Answer (score 1):

A variant of E. Chan-López positional solution

```
a = {{85, 75, 1}, {84, 74, 2}, {83, 73, 3}, {82, 72, 4}, {81, 71, 5}};

b = {{85, 75, 1}, {84, 74, 2}, {83, 73, 3}, {82, 72, 4}, {81, 71, 5}, {80, 70, 6}};

c = {{85, 75, 1}, {84, 74, 2}, {83, 73, 3}, {82, 72, 4}, {81, 71, 5}, {80, 70, 6}, {79, 69, 7}};

m = {a, b, c};
```

Replacement positions

```
p = Position[True] @ Map[Between[{72.3, 74.5}], #[[All, 2]]] & /@ m
```

{{{2}, {3}}, {{2}, {3}}, {{2}, {3}}}

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
MapThread[ReplaceAt[#1, _ :> {-10, 5, 0.3}, #2] &, {m, p}]
```

returns

```
{{{85, 75, 1}, {-10, 5, 0.3}, {-10, 5, 0.3}, {82, 72, 4}, {81, 71, 5}}, 
 {{85, 75, 1}, {-10, 5, 0.3}, {-10, 5, 0.3}, {82, 72, 4}, {81, 71, 5}, {80, 70, 6}}, 
 {{85, 75, 1}, {-10, 5, 0.3}, {-10, 5, 0.3}, {82, 72, 4}, {81, 71, 5}, {80, 70, 6}, {79, 69, 7}}}
```